# how does one predict edges / links / connections on a weighted directed graph network?

Tags: graph-theory

Given an adjacency matrix A for a weighted, directed graph (so matrix elements are not just 0/1 and the matrix is not symmetric), are there any good methods for predicting new edges?

I have a VERY large (billions of nodes) dataset with known edges for some connections and NULL values for unobserved connections, and I would like to use the known edges to make predictions of the unobserved ones.

It is fine if the method is not exact -- in fact, I would like to keep edges NULL or 0 if the prediction is below some threshold, just to keep the matrix as sparse as possible for data size and processing speed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I know this problem as [link prediction](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=link+prediction&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=). It's a novel subject in the semantic web domain. I think people are just beginning to investigate machine learning techniques.